# php mongodb find _id after query

Tags: php, mongodb

I am converting from `mysqli` to `mongodb` and having some problems with basic tasks.
This is part of a login authentication process, if the email and password matches to a record set in the dB i would like to get the `_id` and create a session variable.
Heres what i have so far, all the searches i've done seems to have info on getting the `_id` from different steps and i couldn't modify it for my situation.
Also, if my logic is too literal of a translation from `mysqli`,  please i'm open for suggestions on best practices for `noSql`

```
$collection = $db->members;
$query = array("email" => $email, "password" => $newpass);
  //$cursor = $collection->findOne($query);  // was told this is better but need deeper understanding
$cursor = $collection->find($query); 
$result = $cursor->count();

if($result==1){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

    //having problems here
    $id = $cursor->findOne(array("_id" => $query['_id']));
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

    return true; 
}else 
    return false;
```

**QUESTION** how do i get the `_id` after authenticating a unique username and password?

Comment: plus voted to balance. seems a good question to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not run `findOne` on the cursor. The cursor points to the result from the previous query, you can use [iterator_to_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) to get an array with all the found records. Or you can use findOne() in the first place - it returns the actual row

```
$collection = $db->members;
$query = array("email" => $email, "password" => $newpass);
$result = $collection->findOne($query);

if(!empty($result)){
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

    //having problems here
    $id = "" . $result['_id']; // cast to string, as its a MongoId object
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

    return true; 
}else 
    return false;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can ensure unicity for your query (which is better for a login system) .

So use `findOne()` . It will return you a **document**. Remember in MongoDb, you get document or a cursors of documents.

Check the documentation, you can return only a part of document. [Official Documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields)

```
$doc = $col->findOne(
       array('pass'=> $pass, 'email'=>$email),//select
       array('_id'=>1)//field selection
);
if ($doc){
   //do your session stuff
}
```